# Pass data from parent component into child entry component angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

So I know that I can pass data from a parent to a child using `@Input` like so..

```
<app-component [data]="data"></app-component>

@Input() data: any;
```

now I have a component that gets dynamically added like so..

HTML

```
<app-header></app-header>
<div #entry [vimeoId]="vimeoId"></div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

APP.COMPONENT.TS

```
ngOnInit() {
   this._videoService.videoSource.subscribe((result) => {
      if (result !== '') {
        this.vimeoId = result;
        this.createComponent();
      }
   });
}

createComponent() {
   const factory = this._resolver.resolveComponentFactory(VideoComponent);
   const component = this.entry.createComponent(factory);
}
```

now this isn't working I'm getting this error

`[Angular] Can't bind to 'vimeoId' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.`

now I know why I'm getting this error, its because div doesn't have the @Input so.. my question is how can I pass down data to a dynamically created child component??

Thanks

Comment: @awesomeguy this is not angularjs, this is angular see the title of the post ANGULAR 6, and if you don't know what your talking about why comment?

Comment: oh sorry for my assumption I didn't realize it was what you meant

Comment: The answer is that you can't. There are no input bindings for factory created components. For the same reason there are no input bindings on components created via the router. You can only inject data using the injector. `createComponent` takes an injector as a parameter. You have to create an injector, add providers and pass that to the factory.